# Change weights to integers

Tags: gephi, graph-visualization

I have a project that has weighted edges between nodes. The edges have been imported as floats and have too many values after the decimal to be presentable.

For example, I may have three edges of weights 3.4785949828, 5.2828181992, and 2.4249882928. If I'm showing the weight between nodes, the graph could begin to look very cluttered if I keep all of those values after the decimal. I would like to be able to automatically change them to integer values of 3, 5, and 2 respectively

Is there any way I can automatically change all those floats to integers in the *existing* project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... [edges] have too many values after the decimal to be presentable.

### Data Laboratory

For edge labels, create new column (where `1.234567890` becomes `[1.]`) by using a regular expression like `\d*\.` via:

> `Data Laboratory` > `Data Table` > `Edges` > `Create column with list of regex matching groups`

### Overview

A `Hide non-selected` -option is available via:

> `Overview` > `Labels` -tab > `Hide non-selected`

### Preview

Edge label-display can be adjusted via:

> `Preview` > `Preview Settings` > `Settings` > `Edge Labels` > `Shorten Label`

and

> `Preview` > `Preview Settings` > `Settings` > `Edge Labels` > `Max Characters`

Example:

[image: Steps to reach Gephi's edge label-shortening settings.]